# Does anyone know the touchpad disabling driver for Dell xps 14?

Tags: drivers, touchpad, dell-xps

I accidentally deleted my Dell xps 14 touch pad disabling driver and I don't know where to find it and reinstall it.
I have already tried Dell support and without luck (I don't want to install something that I don't know).

Would anyone please send me the link to that driver

---

**To clarify:** There is this <kbd>Fn</kbd> shortcut key used to disable/enable touch pad in Dell xps14 and when press it orange light on touch pad will lit and touch pad will stop working. But after deleting the driver that responsible for that function,it stopped working. My service center is almost 600 miles away and he said that he forgot to add it last time he fix my laptop.

Since the internet connection at his place is slow,he can't send me from mail either.So can anyone send me the link for that driver. Since I don't really know about drivers it would be really nice if some one show me the driver name or link.

---

Sorry,here is my laptop service tag "C37KWL1".I don't know how to find the specific driver for that function key.My dell has a short cut for disabling touchpad with picture on it along with the other multimedia short cut key with picture. since xps 15 and 17 have seperated touch key instead of on function keys mine have to choose function key or multimedia key through setting.To be honest my service center tech guy forgot to install it when he repair it and can't send me the file(which is about over 20mb or something according to him)for some reason.All i need is that particular file.

Comment: Umm, it's not clear what you mean by "disabling driver", can you clarify it?

Comment: I can't find a Dell XPS 14 laptop in order to see the right touchpad drivers, could you list the exact model?  I can find an XPS M140...

Comment: http://www.dell.com/support/drivers/us/en/04/ServiceTag/C37KWL1

Answer (score 1):

If you disabled the hardware, to to the device manager and re-enable it.  If you deleted the driver, it should be detected as new hardware and automatically reinstalled.

If you don't know how to get to the device manager, a quick way is to go to `Start -> Run` (or hit `WinKey+R`), and type in `devmgmt.msc`.  You should either see a disabled device (red X), or uninstalled/corrupted device (yellow exclamation mark).

Answer (score 1):

You might be able to find the driver at the [Dell Drivers & Downloads](http://support.dell.com/support/downloads/index.aspx?c=us&l=en&s=gen) support page.

Answer (score 0):

**Disable Internal PS/2 Mouse via Local Group Policy**

Run `gpedit.msc` (must be logged on as admin)

Browse to:

> Computer Configuration -> Administrative Templates -> System -> Device
>   Installation -> Device Installation Restrictions

- Click on the ‘Prevent installation of devise that match any of these device IDs’ setting.
- Click Enable and then Show
- Enter the Hardware ID of the touchpad: `ACPI\SYN0608\4&2E5DBFAD&0`
- Click OK
- Close Local Group Policy Edit
- Restart.

**Re-Enable Internal PS/2 Mouse via Local Group Policy**

Run `gpedit.msc` (must be logged on as admin)

Browse to:

> Computer Configuration -> Administrative Templates -> System -> Device
>   Installation -> Device Installation Restrictions

- Click on the ‘Prevent installation of devise that match any of these device IDs’ setting.
- Click Disable
- Click OK
- Close Local Group Policy Edit
- Restart.